# What do TA, TG and M mean on the scheme?

Tags: design

I have a electrical scheme but I can't get what do TA, TG and M mean?

[image: Electrical scheme]

Can anyone explain me?

**P.S.** I am a programmer, not an electrical engineer, so maybe it's a trivial question.

Comment: M is a motor, and TG appears to be a generator. I'm not sure what TA is.

Comment: For slightly more information: I'm guessing the generator is on the same mechanical shaft as the motor, and is acting as a form of feedback.

Comment: TG is a TachoGenerator. TA appears to be some form of inductive spike suppressor - perhaps like a common mode device on 3 phases?

Comment: `A` is usually used for Ammeter, could this be the case?

Comment: TA could maybe be a horrifically badly drawn current transformer group, which would make R33-R35 the burden resistors. This is nasty because for VD1-VD6 to do anything useful with providing current feedback there needs to be a connection from the CTs or the network around VD1-6 to circuit reference (NOT calling it ground in this case!), which is not shown.